# Get Vm using Vrms

Tags: voltage

This is bit of a noob question, but here it goes.

There is a circuit whose input is Vm*sin(wt) and a Vrms of 240V at a freq of 50hz

To get Vm do I just multiply Vrms by sqrt(2)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the 240V represents the RMS value of the input voltage, then yes the peak voltage of a sine wave, defined as Vm here, is the sqrt(2) times the RMS voltage.  Are you sure that the 240V at 50 Hz is an input signal to a circuit.  It seems more like a power supply voltage.

Comment: Its into a half wave rectifier with a freewheeling diode, so ya its a power supply voltage, sorry